# Change django form value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have changed a ForeignKey in a model form, to use a TextBox instead.
Then I override clean method to return the object based on the name field (instead id field)

class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    artist = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

```
def clean_artist(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['artist']
    artist = Artist.objects.get(name=data)
    self.cleaned_data['artist_id'] = artist.id
    return artist

class Meta:
    model = Song
```

It saves the form correctly, how ever when it renders again appears the id value instead the name value. How may I change the display values of a django form? I think overriding **init** will do it, but can't find where is the value property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote Field and Widget subclasses, that solve this particular problem and could be used with JS autocompletion, for example - and is reusable. Still, it required more work than your solution and I'm not sure whether you'll want to use mine or not. Either way - I hope I'll get few upvotes - I spent quite some time and effort writing this...

Instead of defining your ModelForm like you did and messing with `clean_` I suggest something like that:

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    artist = CustomModelChoiceField( queryset = Artist.objects.all(), query_field = "name" )

    class Meta:
        model = Song
```

Now, CustomModelChoiceField (I can't think of better name for the class) is ModelChoiceField subclass, which is good, because we can use `queryset` argument to narrow acceptable choices. If `widget` argument is not present, like above, the default one for this field is used (more about it later). `query_field` is optional and defaults to `"pk"`. So, here is the field code:

```
class CustomModelChoiceField( forms.ModelChoiceField ):
    def __init__( self, queryset, query_field = "pk", **kwargs ):
        if "widget" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["widget"] = ModelTextInput( model_class = queryset.model, query_field = query_field )
        super( CustomModelChoiceField, self ).__init__( queryset, **kwargs )

    def to_python( self, value ):
        try:
            int(value)
        except:
            from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'])
        return super( CustomModelChoiceField, self ).to_python( value )
```

What body of `__init__` means is that setting `widget = None` during creation of `CustomModelChoiceField` gives us plain `ModelChoiceField` (which was very helpful while debugging...). Now, actual work is done in `ModelTextInput` widget:

```
class ModelTextInput( forms.TextInput ):
    def __init__( self, model_class, query_field, attrs = None  ):
        self.model_class = model_class
        self.query_field = query_field
        super( ModelTextInput, self ).__init__( attrs )

    def render(self, name, value, attrs = None ):
        try:
            obj = self.model_class.objects.get( pk = value )
            value = getattr( obj, self.query_field )
        except:
            pass
        return super(ModelTextInput, self).render( name, value, attrs )

    def value_from_datadict( self, data, files, name ):
        try:
            return self.model_class.objects.get( **{ self.query_field : data[name] } ).id
        except:
            return data[name]
```

It's essentially TextInput, that is aware of two additional things - which attribute of which model it represents. ( `model_class` should be replaced with `queryset` for narrowing of possible choices to actually work, I'll fix it later). Looking at implementation of `value_from_datadict` it's easy to spot why `to_python` in the field had to be overridden - it expects `int` value, but does not check if it's true - and just passes the value to associated model, which fails with ugly exception.

I tested this for a while and it works - you can specify different model fields by which form field will try to find your `artist`, form error handling is done automatically by base classes and you don't need to write custom `clean_` method every time you want to use similar functionality.

I'm too tired right now, but I'll try to edit this post (and code) tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I have just got it, the initial hash was what I was missing:

```
if self.instance.id:
    val = self.initial['artist']
    self.initial['artist'] = Artist.objects.get(id=val).name
```